# Flutter Firebase getting list of document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I want to get data as object list

```
 onPressed: () {
     print("entered");
     ProductServices _productServives = ProductServices();
     Future<List<dynamic>> plist = _productServives.getProducts2();
     print(plist);
  },
```

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getProducts2() async {
    CollectionReference ref = _firestore.collection('Products');
    List<Product> productsArray = [];

    ref.snapshots().forEach((element) {
      element.docs.forEach((value) {
        var p = Product.fromSnapshot(value);
        productsArray.add(p);
        print("size: " + productsArray.length.toString());
      });
      // productsArray.add(element);
    });
    print("+ size: " + productsArray.length.toString());

    return productsArray;
  }
```

It is not working as I want line by line.
In for each putting element to the list and increasing the size but because of the working queue returned list is empty.

How can I fix this issue and where can I study asynchronous operation.

Output:

```
I/flutter (29128): entered
I/flutter (29128): + size: 0
I/flutter (29128): Instance of 'Future<List<dynamic>>'
I/flutter (29128): size: 1
I/flutter (29128): size: 2
I/flutter (29128): size: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue coding like this

```
await ref.snapshots().first.then((value) => {
          value.docs.forEach((element) {
            print(element.id);
            var p = Product.fromSnapshot(element);
            productsArray.add(p);
          })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already marked the function as `async`, you can use `await` inside it to mask the asynchronicity a bit:

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getProducts2() async {
  CollectionReference ref = _firestore.collection('Products');
  List<Product> productsArray = [];

  var snapshots = await ref.get()
  snapshots.forEach((element) {
    element.docs.forEach((value) {
      var p = Product.fromSnapshot(value);
      productsArray.add(p);
      print("size: " + productsArray.length.toString());
    });
  });
  print("+ size: " + productsArray.length.toString());

  return productsArray;
}
```

To learn more about futures, and async/await in Flutter: https://www.google.com/search?q=futures%2C+and+async%2Fawait+in+Flutter. In fact, I'm gonna add the first [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY) from that search to my playlist as Andrew is a great explainer.

Comment: The same result on the await I am getting this warning **'await' applied to 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>', which is not a 'Future'**

Comment: ``` await snapshots.forEach((element)```  trying to this but in this case function never ending

Comment: Ah, I missed the `snapshots()` in there. The solution to that new error is to use `get()` instead of `snapshots`. The `get()` function returns a `Future<QuerySnapshot>` (on which you can call `await`), while `snapshots()` returns a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` on which you'd have to `listen()` or (as in your self-answer) call `first()`, but in that case you're just getting the same return as `get()` but while wasting a lot more resources.